# Inherited template class member tests fine in chain constructor, but is "lost" thereafter

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

My base class, `class Foo`, is a template class which has the following constructor:

```
//Declarations
template <class T>
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo::Foo(std::string& root);
    MemberClass obj;
}

template <class T>
Foo<T>::Foo(std::string& root)
{
    MemberClass obj(root); // initialize the member object
    obj.getRoot(); // Prints the string
    // ...
}
```

It has a child class, which is constructed like so:

```
template <class T>
Bar<T>::Bar(std::string& root)
    : Foo<T>(root)
{
    //...
}

template<class T>
void
Bar<T>::accessObj()
{
    this->obj.getRoot();
    // Prints the empty string
}
```

This gives unexpected behaviour, even though no errors are generated. In this case, `getRoot()` will return the empty string.

I have tested this by altering the `Foo` constructor like so:

```
{
    MemberClass obj(root);
    std::cout << &obj << std::endl;
}
```

and the `Bar` constructor like so:

```
//...
    : Foo<T>(root)
{
    std::cout << &this->obj << std::endl;
}
```

The output gives two different locations in memory, which is totally blowing my mind. Why is this the case? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constructor might better look like this:

```
template <class T>
Foo<T>::Foo(std::string& root)
    : obj(root) // initialize the member object
{
    obj.getRoot(); // Prints the string
    // ...
}
```

Before, you were constructing a temporary `obj` in your Foo constructor and throwing it away, never initializing your member variable at all.

If you're using GCC, the option -Wshadow might have helped catch this mistake.

Comment: I apologize. I should have included that in the declarations, MemberClass obj is included there as part of the interface.

Comment: Well I think I guessed what your declarations look like from what you did post.  Do you think my answer is correct or not?

Comment: If "obj" is a member of the class, how is it thrown away after Foo's instantiation? (I am testing your answer, by the way, but also cooking dinner :-) )

Comment: You have two things called obj.  The class member, and the one constructed by this expression: `MemberClass obj(root);`.  This is your problem.

Comment: This definitely fixed my problem (THANK YOU!). I still don't understand why I can instantiate other members of the class within the {} of the constructor and not have them get overwritten, but not objects.

Comment: Hmm, I think that shadowing applies uniformly no matter what type is in play.  Really, try the -Wshadow option to GCC or whatever similar warning exists for your compiler or static code analysis tool.